# Why isn't it assigned, although Array is covariant?

Tags: typescript

Why can be assigned hoge2 and hoge3 but not assigned to hoge1?

```js
const hoge1: { foo: string }[] = [{ foo: 'test', extraVal: 1 }];  // compile error
// Type '{ foo: string; extraVal: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: string; }'.
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'extraVal' does not exist in type '{ foo: string; }'.  TS2322

const val = [{ foo: 'test', extraVal: 1 }];
const hoge2: { foo: string }[] = val;  // ok

const hoge3: { foo: string }[] = (() => [{ foo: 'test', extraVal: 1 }])();  // ok
```

Comment: You can also have a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

Comment: You might want to read the link from @ ford04. In short, object literal  `[{ foo: 'test', extraVal: 1 }]`  get special treatment in typescript. You are responsible to provide correct type so it results in excess property check. But object variable might come from api, etc. so it sneaks the check. It's a design decision.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to load 2 values into a single value array.

`{foo: string }[]` = An array of type string

`[{ foo: 'test', extraVal: 1 }]` = An array of 2 values (string,int)

The error makes sense, you cannot load two values into a single value:

```
// Type '{ foo: string; extraVal: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: string; }'.
```

A solution would be:

```
const hoge1: { foo: string, extraVal: number }[] = [{ foo: 'test', extraVal: 1 }];
```

or, depending on what you are trying to do, possibly:

```
const hoge1: { foo: string }[] = [{ foo: 'test'}, {foo: 'extraVal'}];
```

Note: hoge3 works as it is creating a function with parameters `() => { statements }` which is basically just another string, therefore it is adding a string to an array of strings, which is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
My question is, why trying to assign the same value to `hoge1`, `hoge2`, `hoge3`, but only `hoge1` is not assigned?

Comment: Updated answer with hoge3 explanation, it is creating a function with parameters, which is just a big string, which is then added to the array of strings.